# compiling programs in scientific linux (pcre)

Tags: unix, compilation, pcre

I'm currently trying to install gtk3 on scientific linux (It is not available on official repositories)
I'm well used to yum, apt, pacman etc but i'm a little lost here when it's about compiling ...

to install gtk3, i need glib, to install glib, i need pcre 8.32.

I thus downloaded the tarball from their site.
Once 'untarred', i followed what is written on that link :
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/pcre.html

but once i've made './configure' with its options, 'make', and then 'make install' glib doesn't configure any better... it says my version is still the old version

configure: error: Package requirements (libpcre >= 8.13) were not met:
Requested 'libpcre >= 8.13' but version of libpcre is 7.8

The files seems to be well compiled but not 'moved correctly to the right place' ...
Did i miss something ?
By the way moving to another distro is not an option :P